# When clearing data in excel with macro, it stops entire code from working

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

My vba script was working, but the Sheets.UsedRange.Clear portion was deleting info before the entire script could finish running. I tried moving it to the end of the script, but now the rest of the script has stopped working and only my .Clear portion is working. Could anyone give any suggestions after looking over the script? Any help is appreciated as I no longer have access to my programming expert...

```
Public colH As Integer
Public colA As Integer

Sub Main_Macro()
    Dim HomeT As String
    Dim AwayT As String

    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to copy data from Raw data to Team data?", _
                vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    HomeT = Sheets("Panel").Range("B4")
    AwayT = Sheets("Panel").Range("e4")

    colH = Column_Find(HomeT, "For")
    colA = Column_Find(AwayT, "Against")

    lr = Sheets("Raw data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    Dim pos As String
    With Sheets("Raw data")

        For i = 1 To lr

            If .Cells(i, 1) = "Away" Then Exit For
                If Not .Cells(i, 1) = "Reserves" And Not .Cells(i, 1) = "Home" Then

                ' Get player position
                Sheets("Master").Range("H1") = .Cells(i, 1)

                If Not IsError(Sheets("Master").Range("H2")) Then
                    ' Get player position & allocate points
                    pos = Sheets("Master").Range("H2")
                    Call Allocate_Points(HomeT, AwayT, pos, .Cells(i, "T"))
                End If

            End If

        Next i

        colH = Column_Find(AwayT, "For")
        colA = Column_Find(HomeT, "Against")

        'moving towards away
        For i = i + 1 To lr

            If Not .Cells(i, 1) = "Reserves" And Not .Cells(i, 1) = "" Then

                ' Get player position
                Sheets("Master").Range("H1") = .Cells(i, 1)

                If Not IsError(Sheets("Master").Range("H2")) Then
                    ' Get player position & allocate points
                    pos = Sheets("Master").Range("H2")
                    Call Allocate_Points(AwayT, HomeT, pos, .Cells(i, "T"))
                End If

            End If
        Next i

    End With

End Sub


Sub Allocate_Points(strHTeam As String, _
                    strATeam As String, _
                    strPos As String, _
                    strPoints As Integer)

    lr = Sheets("Team Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row

    With Sheets("Team Data")

        For i = 1 To lr
            If .Cells(i, 2) = strHTeam And .Cells(i, 4) = strPos And .Cells(i, 3) = "For" Then
                ' HOME TEAM
                lc = Sheets("Team Data").Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                .Cells(i, colH + 1) = Val(.Cells(i, colH + 1)) + Val(strPoints)
            ElseIf .Cells(i, 2) = strATeam And .Cells(i, 4) = strPos And .Cells(i, 3) = "Against" Then
                ' AWAY
                lc = Sheets("Team Data").Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                .Cells(i, colA + 1) = Val(.Cells(i, colA + 1)) + Val(strPoints)
            End If
        Next i

    End With
End Sub


Function Column_Find(strTeam As String, StrFA As String) As Integer

    lr = Sheets("Team Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row

    With Sheets("Team Data")

        For i = 1 To lr

            If .Cells(i, 2) = strTeam And .Cells(i, 3) = StrFA Then
                ' HOME TEAM
                lc = Sheets("Team Data").Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                Column_Find = lc

                'clear raw data
                Sheets("raw data").UsedRange.Clear
                Sheets("raw data").Range("A1") = "Home"
                Sheets("raw data").Range("A16") = "Away"
                MsgBox "Operation Successfull !!! " & vbclrlf & vbCrLf & "Data pasted to Team data    Completed", vbInformation
                Exit Function
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Function
```

Comment: you are going to get some downvotes, stackoverflow is not like 'fix my code', it is for peple who want to learn

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try altering the following block of code as follows:

From:

```
For i = 1 To lr
    If .Cells(i, 2) = strTeam And .Cells(i, 3) = StrFA Then
        ' HOME TEAM
        lc = Sheets("Team Data").Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Column_Find = lc

        'clear raw data
        Sheets("raw data").UsedRange.Clear
        Sheets("raw data").Range("A1") = "Home"
        Sheets("raw data").Range("A16") = "Away"
        MsgBox "Operation Successfull !!! " & vbclrlf & vbCrLf & "Data pasted to Team data    Completed", vbInformation
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i
```

To:

```
For i = 1 To lr
    If .Cells(i, 2) = strTeam And .Cells(i, 3) = StrFA Then
        ' HOME TEAM
        lc = Sheets("Team Data").Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Column_Find = lc
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i

'clear raw data
Sheets("raw data").UsedRange.Clear
Sheets("raw data").Range("A1") = "Home"
Sheets("raw data").Range("A16") = "Away"
MsgBox "Operation Successfull !!! " & vbclrlf & vbCrLf & "Data pasted to Team data    Completed", vbInformation
```

This allows your loop to iterate all the way through before trying to delete all of the raw data it's working with. Without having the source workbook, it is difficult to pinpoint the problem.. but as you've stated it is clearing the data prematurely and this is likely where the fault is. If not here, then the function is being called prematurely.